# Offline menu & searching app with datatables. Indexeddb, or nw.js, or?

Tags: datatables, indexeddb, offline-caching, offlineapps, nw.js

Good evening. I'm Alex from FL, currently at the solidarity farm in Argentina (www.facebook.com/granjasolidaria).

I'm creating a simple Bible app, to give out freely, to lots of people who help us visit the children, in the poorest villages here in South America.

Unfortunately I have not found a real programmer to do it for us. Who, me? .. very limited knowledge of html/css/js. However, I was able to put together pretty much everything I want. Basically, 1. Browse the Bible with a menu, and 2. Search/filter the Bible on keyup. That's it!

I've learned a bit of datatables and then... That's right! It takes long to load the whole Bible text... but even worse, the keyup searches are just not good at all. It takes for ever to filter.

What have I tried? I tried using different data sources, although I suspect server side processing will make everything faster, however, I just don't know enough to connect to a db (I tried very hard with php/mysql), plus, as crazy as it sounds, a lot of people down here don't have access to internet, so offline is really needed. Do I want to try learning indexeddb, or nw.js, or? Feel free to say something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to consider lots of factors here.
First you stated internet is not a common thing there so you  need something offline. Nw.js is good for this task.

What kind of pc ppl using there? What kind of op system? Win xp, win98? Vista or newer? Linux?  Nw.js only supports winxp or newer , linux and mac.

About optimalization. What kind of format your data has? Searching and filtering in memory is pretty fast if its optimized nicely. In nw.js you can use indexeddb and also offline databases where you can run real queries like sqllite.  Nw.js can be a good choice but at this point I need more info and code you already have to help forward.